# Use TestFlight for "Internal Distribution"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, testflight

We currently have an app that we would like to distribute among people in our organization, and since we are an organization, not an enterprise, our developer account is also organizational, not enterprise. That means we cannot use the enterprise distribution that Apple offers. We know that the user count can be easily 7000+, so Ad-hoc is not possible either, since it caps at 100 users.

Since Apple allows a max of 10,000 users on public beta testing through TestFlight, and, to my knowledge, once the first build is approved for public beta testing then the subsequent ones no longer requires reviewing. **Therefore, can we infinitely have our app on public beta testing without ever publishing to the App Store?** We know a new build is required for every 90 days; I'm just worried if this is against Apple's policies or if there will be any penalties if we get caught.

Comment: You should use a custom B2B app and obtain the app via Apple Business Manager. For public beta review is required for each new version, but not for new builds within a version.  TestFlight builds will expire, as you noted, requiring the user to update their app.  Also, there is a good possibility that an app designed for a specific organisation won't pass review for the App Store since it won't be a general purpose app. B2B custom app avoids all of this.

Comment: Watch this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/304/